# What does "P+ ID P-" mean on this battery flex?

Tags: batteries, flex

My nokia 6.1 plus battery has these labels on it's flex. The phone has been off for about a year and doesn't get ON so I want to shock it's battery. The problem is I do not know battery terminals and the polarities. What are the terminals?

Image taken from https://www.impextrom.com
[image]

Comment: "Shocking" a lithium battery sounds like an incredibly bad idea. If the battery is dead and won't take a charge, replace it.

Comment: ask Nokia .....

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Well, at the time, battery was in a very good condition. I read elsewhere if we put about 7.5V on the terminals, it may help it get back. Also there is this board on the market that repair shops use to bring dead battere's back to the life. I will try once in a safe garage :) https://shopee.com.my/OSS-TEAM-W223-PRO-BATTERY-CHARGING-AND-BATTERY-ACTIVATE-BOARD-i.369291555.8008165741

Comment: Just remember, you can't throw water on a lithium fire.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson, Yeah I know. Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson well you _can_, and the _fire_ may appreciate it.  But it's not going to solve your "I have a fire" problem.

Comment: @TimWescott Yes, well put!

Comment: @Behzad Although the procedure might bring a dead battery back to life, note that it will certainly not be in a "very good" condition. More like "barely working". A battery that got drained so much that the phone refuses to charge it is permanently damaged and at a small fraction of the original capacity. Better replace it if you want to use the phone.

Comment: Please return to this question once done "shocking" the battery, and describe your results (did it work, not work, etc.)

Comment: @rdtsc, Well, it didn't work and I gave up :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

it (and the row above it) are the labels for the terminals of that snap connector

```
 power+     id               power-

 power+     temperature      power-
```